# git log - exluding commits that happened on merged branches

Tags: git

when I run "git log e4bf97f044d40f01486e878614118dcc5270633c..origin/branchA --name-status" -  I get all commits including the ones that were not direct commits of the branch I specify.  How do I filter out those commits? Filtering out specific branches wont work because I won't know their names. I have tried numerous git log options that I found but none of them seem to give me what I need.

In case such as this: where branchB was created from branchA, later on I create a same file in branchA and branchB, then at some point I modify the file in branchA and finally I merge branchB back into branchA once branchB is no longer dev status.

What I need to do with git log is show a list of commit shas with corresponding filenames and file status  The output that I would get from above case is this:

```
 459925641be77a18d4c9a649b904adaa684a14cb branchB

    M /ui/pom.xml

 cf7de161f17d4ec1fb0f9c04ead11848a7167431 branchA

    M /ui/pom.xml

 331c7a032c8be6e922bc19bf1659c79f289d397b branchB

    A /ui/pom.xml

 187a319ea67a5eb44eccd1ddbeb3072c3cf2eb01 branchA

    A /ui/pom.xml
```

Above output I would parse to remove duplicate file names but for the file status it is a bit more complicated.  After generating the report I have to review it.  For newly added files I have to take approach A while for modified files I need to take approach B.  How do I correctly determine the correct file status if I am also getting commits from other branches in my git log output keep in mind that the newly added file was at some point already reviewed before branchB was merged into branchA so I only have to take approach A at this point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `--first-parent`